# VideoJS does not show subtitles

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I am implemented videoplayer in our web-site with VideoJS and have the follow problem.

The player is initialized with follow data setup:

```
var video_setup = { 'controls': true,
                    'preload': 'none',
                    'playbackRates': [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 3],
                    'poster': getPosterUrl(jsonObject),
                    'tracks': [
                        { src: 'video/0546_prepod_01H.vtt', kind: 'subtitles', srclang: 'ru', label: 'Русский' },
                    ],
                    'plugins': {
                        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
                            default: 'low',
                            dynamicLabel: true
                        }
                    }};
```

But after this I can see subtitles only in Firefox. In Google Chrome and Internet Explorer there is not a subtitles switcher.

Also I have tried to use `addRemoteTextTrack` function. It added subtitles switcher but nothing happens when I switch subtitles on.

Is there any way to activate subtitles in all browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after adding to data setup

```
'html5': {
    nativeTextTracks: false
},
```